# Kohana validation without message files

Tags: php, validation, kohana

Is there a way to use Kohana's (3+) validation class without using message files?

[EDIT]

Here is an example:

```
$post = Validate::factory($_POST);
$post
    ->rule('username', 'not_empty')
    ->rule('username', 'regex', array('/^[a-z_.]++$/iD'))

    ->rule('password', 'not_empty')
    ->rule('password', 'min_length', array('6'))
    ->rule('confirm',  'matches', array('password'))

    ->rule('use_ssl', 'not_empty');
```

The error message will be readed from message files, but I want to hardcode the error messages in source code. For example:

```
$post->rules->('username', 'not_empty', 'Please give your username');
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without using message files"?  Do you want to set validation error messages from another source?

Comment: You're going to cause problems in your code.

Comment: @ThePixelDeveloper I cause problems if I hardcode the error messages in code, or are your reffering to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to extend the Validation `public function errors($file = NULL, $translate = TRUE)` `public function rules($field, array $rules)` and `public function rule($field, $rule, array $params = NULL)` methods and implement with your own code.

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is the only way to do it. I think I will write my own lightweight validation class.